# Able to set Bounties at 74 rep?

Tags: support, reputation

I have just received a notification saying that I can now set bounties. But I know I can't until I have at least 75 rep. I currently only have 74 rep on Unix & Linux.

Can someone please help me figure out what is happening?

Is this a bug or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is posted [all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70875/notification-for-moderator-tools-went-off-too-early) [the](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111640/new-privilege-notification-shows-before-i-get-the-new-privilege) [time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129389/receiving-new-privilege-notification-before-reaching-threshold) on the main meta. In short, you hit 75 rep at some point and the notification script happened to see it there before you dropped back under again. Possibly you were at 76 and then got downvoted (-2), or were at 75 and then downvoted somebody else (-1), or somebody upvoted you and then took the vote back

Comment: Ah understandable. I saw in my reputation points, that I had no downvotes, so maybe someone did upvote me then took it back. Thanks for that.